# Python syntax checkers (Pylint, Prospector...) crashing with KeyError: 'repoze.who' when run from inside Vim

Tags: python, vim, pylint, syntastic, repoze.who

I'm having a problem with running pylint from inside vim (which you need to do if you are using the [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) plugin).

For example `:!pylint --version` crashes with this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                  
  File "/home/seanh/.virtualenvs/ckan/bin/pylint", line 5, in <module>                                                                                                              
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point                                                                                                                                      
  File "/home/seanh/.virtualenvs/ckan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2736, in <module>                                                                         
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/seanh/.virtualenvs/ckan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 698, in subscribe                                                                         
    callback(dist)                                                                                                                                                                  
  File "/home/seanh/.virtualenvs/ckan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2736, in <lambda>                                                                         
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/seanh/.virtualenvs/ckan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2274, in activate                                                                         
    list(map(declare_namespace, self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt')))                                                                                                      
  File "/home/seanh/.virtualenvs/ckan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1870, in declare_namespace                                                                
    path = sys.modules[parent].__path__                                                                                                                                             
KeyError: 'repoze.who'
```

I've also seen the same error [prospector](http://prospector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) running inside Vim.

But I cannot reproduce the error from outside of Vim. In a shell. If I activate my Python virtual environment in a shell then run `pylint --version` I get:

```
$ pylint --version
Warning: option include-ids is deprecated and ignored.
Warning: option symbols is deprecated and ignored.
pylint 1.3.1, 
astroid 1.2.1, common 0.62.1
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
```

If I then run `vim` in the same shell and do `:!pylint --version` in Vim I get the traceback above. Quit Vim and run `pylint --version` in the shell again and it's fine.

There must be something different between the environment that vim runs the command in and my shell environment, that is triggering the crash. But I don't know how to investigate this, hence this question with the vim tag.

`repoze.who` is also implicated here. If I destroy my virtualenv and create a new virtualenv with nothing but pylint and other syntax checkers installed in it, then everything works fine both inside and outside of vim. But if I then `pip install repoze.who==1.0.19` in the virtualenv then the pylint crash above reappears when running `:!pylint --version` in vim (but not when running it in my shell).

Vim version 7.4 installed from package on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with repoze.who 1.0.19. `pip install -U repoze.who==2.2` in the virtualenv gets rid of the problem. Weirdly you can then do `pip install -U repoze.who==1.0.19` and downgrade it, and the pylint crash is still gone. I never got to the bottom of what exactly is causing it, but I suspect it may be something to do with this item from the repoze.who 2.0a1 changelog: Remove ez_setup.py and dependency on it in setup.py (support distribute).